# jquery.html() interpret html entities

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I'm dealing with a rich text editor, but when I try to insert hmtl entities in my "contenteditable" div using jQuery.html() these entities get interpreted.

If I do:

```
<textarea><b>Hey, look.. this is how do yo make your text bold:</b>&gt;b&lt&;{text}&gt;/b&lt;</textarea>
```

And trying to convert that textarea in a rich text editor using:

```
this.$editor.html($textarea.val());
```

What I expect:

**Hey, look.. this is how do yo make your text bold:**

```
<b>{text}</b>
```

What I get:

**Hey, look.. this is how do yo make your text bold:**
**{text}**

Obviously, I cant use jQuery.text() in this case... Any ideas? Change my editor it's not a choice.

EDIT: Example, here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nNuKk/3/

Comment: Give your RTE a code button that places said html in <pre> and/or <code> tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per jsfiddle in comment 
Here is [Another working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nNuKk/4/)
the key here is to `escape` even the ampersand `&` in `&lt;` or `&gt;`.

just make the text in text area look like below

```
 <b>Hey, look.. this is how do you make your text bold:</b>
&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;{text}&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;
```

If this what you are looking for accept the answer:) or let me know your comments/concerns.

---

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SPU6E/2/)
Suppose

```
 <body>
    <textarea id="myid"><b>Hey, look.. this is how do yo make your text bold:</b>&gt;b&lt&;{text}&gt;/b&lt;</textarea>

    <div id=2>

    </div>
</body>
```

and then javascript

```
   $("#2").text($("#myid").val());
```

SO in your case you should use

```
this.$editor.text($textarea.val());
```

instead of

```
this.$editor.html($textarea.val());
```

If this does not work let me know what element type is your `$editor` `textarea` or`span` or anything else

If above does not work try this

```
 var temp=$("<div></div>").text($textarea.val()).html(); //temp will contain the escaped representation
 this.$editor.html(temp);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for JS Fiddle updating answer

Comment: It's so obvious that I cannot believe that I haven't realized before. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You've left out details - like which rich editor your using but it sounds like .html() that your editor is using is not the same as .html() which jquery uses to manipulate the DOM (since if that were the case, what you're trying to do would work)

Your actual solution will depend on the implementation of the editor in question...

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I just add a link with code example, check it ;)

Comment: Alright, the problem is you can't have it both ways.. If you use .val(), you'll get the value of the textarea which inteperts the entities as their underlying characters.. If you change it to use .html() on the textarea you'll get the content with the tags..